# How to correcly redefine javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, redefine

```
var test = {};
test.k1 = {};
console.log(test);
test.k1.k2 = 'apple';
console.log(test);
test.k1.k2 = 'banana';
```

First log:
*Object k1:Object k2:"banana"*
**WHY?** I expect empty object k1... banana is defined 3 lines later

Second log:
*Object k1:Object k2:"banana"*
**WHY?** I expect k2: apple... banana is defined in next line

Comment: This answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: @Tresdin: We can go with that as an original for marking this as a dupe. I feel like there's a better version of that out there, but it'll do. *Edit*: Ah, Quentin got there first.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is correct, it's the `console.log` that's throwing you. In some environments, particularly browsers, what `console.log` logs is a **live** reference to the object, and so if you expand it after the line assigning banana, you see banana instead of apple because it's showing it to you as it was when you expanded it, not when you logged it.